# Lowest common ancestor in recursive tree traversal

Tags: java, optimization, algorithm, recursion, tree

LCA = [Lowest Common Ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor)

The following code finds the lowest common ancestor in tree of nodes, where a node can have two parents, left and right.

The tree looks like this:

```
     J-K
    /   \
 E-F-G-H-I
```

And K and H input, the output is F

```
public TreeSet<Node> find(Node node, TreeSet<Node> nodeSet) {
    nodeSet.add(node);
    if (node.getLeft() != null) {
        find(node.getLeft(), nodeSet);
    }
    if (node.getRight() != null) {
        find(node.getRight(), nodeSet);
    }

    return nodeSet;
}
```

which is called here:

```
TreeSet<Node> nodeList1 = new TreeSet<Node>();
TreeSet<Node> nodeList2 = new TreeSet<Node>();
nodeList1 = find(node1, nodesList1); // node1 = K
nodeList2 = find(node2, nodesList2); // node2 = H
Iterator iterator = nodeList1.descendingIterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()){
    Node node = (Node) iterator.next();
    if(nodeList2.contains(node)){
      return node.getValue();
    }
}
```

and a `Node` looks like you'd expect and implements comparable.

Is my implementation O(n), I think it is, but can it be improved?

The relvant snippet of `Node`:

```
class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    private String value;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.getValue().hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node o) {
            return this.getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: You use the words *"finds the lowest common ancestor in tree of nodes"* but the picture you draw is not a tree, and nowhere in your code do you have a 'root'... your 'find' method just builds a set of **children**, not **ancestors**. Does your code work?

Comment: @rolfl ok, what would you call the picture ? children/ancestors semantics ? Yes the code works.

Comment: @NimChimpsky - A tree does not contain cycles... yet your picture shows a cycle. Since your node does not contain a 'parent' pointer, you cannot find the 'parent' of either of your nodes, so you cannot scan 'up' the tree. And, since you do not show us where you keep the 'root', there is no apparent way to find the 'ancestors' of either node. Which means your code will only work if `node1` is a child of `node2` (or `node2` is a child of `node1`)

Comment: @rolfl left and right are parents, the root node is available... I just haven't used it.

Comment: This data structure is not a tree.

Comment: @rolfl ok, not arguing with you ... any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naming** - the method `find(Node, TreeSet<Node>)` implies it will find the `Node` inside the `TreeSet`, which, of course it doesn't - a better name might be `buildNodeParents` or something like that.

Also, your `Node` has `getLeft()` and `getRight()`. In most implementations of a node tree, `left` and `right` implied the node's *children*. In your case, for clarity - I would have called those methods `getLeftParent()` and `getRightParent()`.

**Algorithm**

I assume your node implements `Comparable` (because you are using descendingIterator()) it would be useful if you've added that code, so complexity will be more easily calculated - how does it know if it is lower than another node? Maybe I've missed the correct definition for 'lowest' from your description? The sample tree you've shown is not very clear...

**Complexity**

Your algorithm's complexity is \$O(n) * (O(i) + O(f))\$ where `n` is the number of the nodes in your tree, `i` is the complexity of inserting a single value to the `TreeSet` (`add()`), and `f` is the complexity of finding a single value to the `TreeSet` (`contains()`). Assuming the `Node.compareTo` is of complexity \$O(1)\$, AFAIK `TreeSet` complexity is \$O(log(n))\$.

This means that your algorithm's complexity is *at least* \$O(n \cdot log(n))\$

To achieve complexity of \$O(n)\$, I would choose a `HashSet` (which has complexity \$O(1)\$ for inserting and finding elements) over `TreeSet`. Then in the last part of the algorithm, instead of returning the *first* mutual ancestor, return the *lowest* mutual ancestor:

```
HashSet<Node> nodeList1 = new HashSet<Node>();
HashSet<Node> nodeList2 = new HashSet<Node>();
nodeList1 = find(node1, nodesList1); // node1 = K
nodeList2 = find(node2, nodesList2); // node2 = H
Iterator iterator = nodeList1.iterator();
Node minimalNode = null
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  Node node = (Node) iterator.next();
  if(nodeList2.contains(node)){
    if (minimalNode == null || node.compareTo(minimalNode) < 0) {
      minimalNode = node;
    }
  }
}
return minimalNode;
```

This has, again the same complexity of \$O(n) * (O(i) + O(f))\$, but in this case \$O(i)\$ and \$O(f)\$ are \$O(1)\$ - so the total complexity is \$O(n)\$.

Comment: Added a suggestion for O(n)

Comment: @UriAgassi can you figure out how the ancestor of two nodes is somewhere in the intersection of the descendants of two nodes?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - no, because `LinkedList` has a find complexity of `O(n)` - this would make for a total complexity of `O(n^2)`. @rolfl - you can see that my second passage - my assumption was that `getLeft()` and `getRight()` are actually `getLeftParent()` and `getRightLeft()`...

Comment: @UriAgassi oh yes of course. Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be have a few misconceptions, as @rolfl points out.

First, the data structure you have described and illustrated does not fit the definition of a [tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/tree/info).  Rather, I would characterize your data structure as a graph of maximum in-degree 2.

Second, you seem to be under the impression that the `TreeSet` internally contains a tree that resembles part of your original graph.  Actually, a `TreeSet` is nothing more than a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html); the fact that the `SortedSet` is implemented by using a tree internally is irrelevant to you.  `nodeList1.descendingIterator()` does not produce an iterator that walks from root to leaf.  Rather, it yields nodes reverse-sorted according to the value contained in the node.

As a result, the code does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor note: you could add the `Node` type to the iterator which would make the casting unnecessary and would remove the compiler warning:

```
Iterator<Node> iterator = nodeList1.descendingIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Node node = iterator.next();
```